# Tagging a string with corresponding symbol

Tags: haskell, types, gadt

I would like an easy way to create a `String` tagged with itself. Right now I can
do something like:

```
data TagString :: Symbol -> * where
    Tag :: String -> TagString s
    deriving Show

tag :: KnownSymbol s => Proxy s -> TagString s
tag s = Tag (symbolVal s)
```

and use it like

```
tag (Proxy :: Proxy "blah")
```

But this is not nice because

- The guarantee about the tag is only provided by `tag` not by the GADT.
- Every time I want to create a value I have to provide a type signature, which
  gets unwieldy if the value is part of some bigger expression.

Is there any way to improve this, preferably going in the opposite direction, i.e. from `String` to `Symbol`? I would like to write `Tag "blah"` and have ghc infer the type
`TagString "blah"`.

GHC.TypeLits provides the `someSymbolVal` function which looks somewhat
related but it produces a `SomeSymbol`, not a `Symbol` and I can quite grasp how to use
it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *Is there any way to improve this, preferably going in the opposite direction, i.e. from String to Symbol?*

There is no way to go directly from `String` to `Symbol`, because Haskell isn't dependently typed, unfortunately. You do have to write out a type annotation every time you want a new value and there isn't an existing tag with the desired symbol already around.

> *The guarantee about the tag is only provided by tag not by the GADT.*

The following should work well (in fact, the same type can be found in the `singletons` package):

```
data SSym :: Symbol -> * where
    SSym :: KnownSymbol s => SSym s

-- defining values
sym1 = SSym :: SSym "foo"
sym2 = SSym :: SSym "bar"
```

This type essentially differs from `Proxy` only by having the `KnownSymbol` dictionary in the constructor. The dictionary lets us recover the string contained within even if the symbol is not known statically:

```
extractString :: SSym s -> String
extractString s@SSym = symbolVal s
```

We pattern matched on `SSym`, thereby bringing into scope the implicit `KnownSymbol` dictionary. The same doesn't work with a mere `Proxy`:

```
extractString' :: forall (s :: Symbol). Proxy s -> String
extractString' p@Proxy = symbolVal p 
-- type error, we can't recover the string from anywhere
```

> *... it produces a SomeSymbol, not a Symbol and I can quite grasp how to use it.*

`SomeSymbol` is like `SSym` except it hides the string it carries around so that it doesn't appear in the type. The string can be recovered by pattern matching on the constructor.

```
extractString'' :: SomeSymbol -> String
extractString'' (SomeSymbol proxy) = symbolVal proxy
```

It can be useful when you want to manipulate different symbols in bulk, for example you can put them in a list (which you can't do with different `SSym`-s, because their types differ).

Comment: Great explanation. I had no idea you could put a dictionary in a GADT constructor like that. It looks very useful. Thanks!